# Full Text Search in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named as **tblJobs**  on which i want to implement **Full Text Search**.
 There is a column named as **jobdescription**  on which search is to be implemented.
 I m using SQL Server 2008 (RTM)..,but still my option of **full-text Index** is disabled. I did lots of thing, follow every steps from various websites.., but nothing seems to be helpfull. Can anyone pls help me to get out of this prolem.
  Thanks in advance..!

Comment: What do you mean it's disabled? Can you create a full text catalog?

Comment: Can you check if it even has been installed? I can see no other reason, since databases are FTS  enabled by default in 2008 and newer.